# QT: Who is the parent of members of a QActionGroup after it is added to a QMenu?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

In [this example](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-mainwindows-menus-example.html), a handful of `QAction` objects are added to a `QActionGroup`. Then later, the same actions are added to `QMenu` as actions. The documentation for `QActionGroup` suggests adding a `QAction` by passing in the `QActionGroup` as the parent to the `QAction` construction. However, I believe adding an action to a `QMenu` makes the QMenu the parent.

Who would be the parent in the example (i.e., action added to the action group first, then to the menu)?

More generally, if you do an action that sets the parent, does the parent transfer completely (i.e., the object's parent gets set to the Menu *and* is deleted from the QActionGroup child list)? I would expect so, but I couldn't see this written anywhere and would like confirmation.

I'm asking because I'm doing fairly innocuous actions but am seeing crashes that suggest double frees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's check using the `parent()` method:

```
...
leftAlignAct = new QAction(tr("&Left Align"), this);
qDebug()<<"0"<<leftAlignAct->parent();
...
alignmentGroup->addAction(leftAlignAct);
qDebug()<<"1"<<leftAlignAct->parent();
...
formatMenu->addAction(leftAlignAct);
qDebug()<<"2"<<leftAlignAct->parent();
...
```

Output:

```
0 MainWindow(0x7fffd078fe80) 
1 MainWindow(0x7fffd078fe80) 
2 MainWindow(0x7fffd078fe80)
```

Clearly the parent of `QAction` never changed and this was established in his creation so the `QMenu` or the `QActionGroup` appropriate `QAction`

---

In fact, the parent that you pass to QAction will not be changed by QMenu or QActionGroup. It would not be good for QMenu to take ownership of the QAction since a QAction can be part of the QMenu and a QToolBar. and in the QActionGroup your task is to modify the state depending on the other QAction, there is no need to appropriate QAction. If you want to set QActionGroup or QMenu to be the parent then use setParent()

Comment: Neither reparents...that's surprising. You did this with Qt4, correct?

Comment: @MrMas 
Yes, I am using 4.8.7 :)

Comment: So...you can make the action's parent the qactiongroup or the qmenu, but adding the action to the menu or the group doesn't reparent the action and so the menu and the group don't add the actions to a child list.

Comment: @MrMas 
In fact, the parent that you pass to QAction will not be changed by QMenu or QActionGroup. It would not be good for QMenu to take ownership of the QAction since a QAction can be part of the QMenu and a QToolBar. and in the QActionGroup your task is to modify the state depending on the other QAction, there is no need to appropriate QAction. If you want to set QActionGroup or QMenu to be the parent then use setParent()

Comment: In this case, I think the doubt came from ignorance.

Comment: Although not directly addressing the question, I believe it is important to keep in mind: QAction and QMenu never become parents (unless explicitly passed as the parent in the constructor), they do not hold any of the actions as children.